# Why do i can't get my container content in Azure blob storage

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-blob-storage

So i tried to list all my content in container, but it keeps crashing my app.

I tried a sample code from documentation, but it still happens:

```
async function listBlobs(blobServiceClient, containerName) {
    const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);

    let i = 1;
    let blobs = containerClient.listBlobsFlat();
    for await (const blob of blobs) {
        console.log(`Blob ${i++}: ${blob.name}`);
    }
}
```

blobServiceClient - seems to work fine, and i found that problem is in blob.name, but how to fix it idk. Help me
[Here`s how it looks inside container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00MKr.png)

Comment: What is the error are you getting? What line of code is it on?

Comment: Well, nothing appears on my error page, but in my debug-log it says:
[14:07:35.221 UTC] ← From target: {"method":"Runtime.executionContextDestroyed","params":{"executionContextId":1}}
[14:07:35.221 UTC] Killing process with id: 23412
[14:07:35.559 UTC] Terminated: Program ended

Comment: It could be that your program exited normally (if you don't wait for `listBlobs()` call to complete).  How did you invoke `listBlobs`?